# Java MySQL and JFrame connection "Cannot convert from boolean to connection"

Tags: java, android, mysql, swing, import

public class BancoDeDados {

```
static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Estoque";
static String pass = "admin";
static String user = "admin";
static Connection conexao = null;

public static boolean conecta() throws ClassNotFoundException {

    try {
        Class.forName("mysql.Driver");
        conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        //System.out.println("Conectado.");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conectado com Sucesso!");
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuário e/ou senha estão incorretos!");
        //System.out.println("Usuário e/ou senha estão errados.");
        return false;
    }

}
```

public class TelaPrincipal extends JFrame {

```
Connection conexao = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;
ResultSet rs = null;


private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textLogin;
private JPasswordField textSenha;





public void logar(){
    String sql = "Select *from Login WHERE Usuario = ? and senha = ?";
    try{
        pst = conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, textLogin.getText());
        pst.setString(2, textSenha.getText());
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()){
            TelaOpcoes telaopcoes = new TelaOpcoes();
            telaopcoes.setVisible(true);
            dispose();      
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuário e Senha Inválidos");
        }

    }

    catch(SQLException error){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, error);

    }
}


/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                TelaPrincipal frame = new TelaPrincipal();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public TelaPrincipal() throws ClassNotFoundException {

    conexao = BancoDeDados.conecta();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

Its doing error on penultimate line " CONEXAO = BANCODEDADOS.CONECTA(); " saying that "Type mismatch : cannot convert from boolean to Connection"
Can somebody help me please? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CONEXAO = BANCODEDADOS.CONECTA();

Here CONEXAO is a connection variable

but the method 
BANCODEDADOS.CONECTA(); returns a boolean value.

so change the type of variable CONEXAO

or create a new variable boolean type for store the result
Boolean conexao = BancoDeDados.conecta();

Comment: i did it and the error has disappeared but when i run , on console appeared it: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mysql.Driver

Comment: you must create a connection with database example String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";                    String USER = "root";
    String PASS = "12345678";                                                                try
  {
//STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");


            //STEP 3: Open a connection
            System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER,PASS);   }   catch(Exception e) {}

Answer (score 0):

`conexao` is object of `Connection` and you are assigning value of method call `BancoDeDados.conecta();`[Which return `boolean`] to `Connection`.

Change your code like

```
Boolean result = BancoDeDados.conecta();
```

Or return `conexao` from method `conecta` to support your code.

**Edit:**

Driver to connect MySQL is `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. Change your code

```
Class.forName("mysql.Driver");
```

to

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Comment: i did it and the error has disappeared but when i run , on console appeared it: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mysql.Driver

Answer (score 0):

Your method returns a boolean (not a `Connection`). Change

```
public static boolean conecta() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    try {
        Class.forName("mysql.Driver");
        conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        //System.out.println("Conectado.");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conectado com Sucesso!");
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuário e/ou senha estão incorretos!");
        //System.out.println("Usuário e/ou senha estão errados.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

to something like

```
public static Connection conecta() {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("mysql.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return conn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning boolean from method `conecta()` and in constructor you are storing it to `java.sql.Connection`...

So change the return type of `conecta()` method to `java.sql.Connection`..